# Count times attribute 'ABC' value's changed within a collection

Tags: java, list, count, java-stream, aggregate

I'm currently using Java 8 and cannot switch to later versions. Since I couldn't find anything similar, maybe someone knows an already implemented solution. It can be a third-party library or use lambda, etc. No restrictions. Any help is appreciated!

There is a list with this structure, e.g.:

```
| ID | Date       | Status | Name | Description      | Currency |
|----|------------|--------|------|------------------|----------|
| 1  | 2019-10-01 | 1      | 'A'  | 'Description A'  | USD      |
| 1  | 2019-10-01 | 3      | 'A'  | 'Description A2' | USD      |
| 1  | 2019-10-01 | 4      | 'A2' | 'Description A2' | USD      |
| 2  | 2019-10-03 | 1      | 'B'  | 'Description B'  | USD      |
| 2  | 2019-10-03 | 2      | 'B'  | 'Description B'  | BRL      |
| 2  | 2019-10-03 | 4      | 'B'  | 'Description B'  | USD      |
| 3  | 2019-10-05 | 1      | 'C'  | 'Description C'  | JPY      |
| 3  | 2019-10-05 | 2      | 'C'  | 'Description C2' | JPY      |
```

The problem is creating another list based on the original list with the fields:

1. Date;
2. ID;
3. Times Status changed;
4. Times Name or Description changed;
5. Times Currency changed;

Also, more fields are required (if that makes the question too complex I can separate it into other questions):

6. Days between the date of last change and the first date of the specific ID (something called "aging");
7. Display the type of the changes:

7.1 'Name/Description' if only Name OR Description changed

7.2 'Currency' if only Currency changed

7.3 'Both' if Name OR Description AND Currency changed

It's not necessary to be a `List`. It can be any type of collection.

The first list comes from a SQL query. That's what I began coding:

```
public List<Obj> getResultList() {
    List<Obj> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
    Map<String, Integer> counterMap = new HashMap<>();

    counterMap.put("status", 0);
    counterMap.put("name", 0);
    counterMap.put("description", 0);
    counterMap.put("currency", 0);

    StreamEx.of(sourceList).forPairs((current, next) -> {
        compareCurrentAndNext(current, next);
    });

    int countStatus = counterMap.get("status");

    // etc
}

private void compareCurrentAndNext(final Obj current,
                                   final Obj next) {
    if (current.getId().equals(next.getId())) {
        if (!current.getStatus().equals(next.getStatus())) {
            counterMap.replace("status", counterMap.get("status") + 1);
        }

        // etc
    }
}
```

It uses StreamEx library (https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>one.util</groupId>
  <artifactId>streamex</artifactId>
  <version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Actually, there are many more attributes and I simplified the real problem here.

Comment: What have you tried, or are you simply hoping we'll write your code for you? --- What did you expect the output to be for that input?

Comment: Added info about it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a new list (`resultList`), with each entry in the list having 5 (or more) properties, you should start by creating a class with 5 (or more) fields.

This is not the class called `Obj` (which BTW is a really bad name), since the result properties are different from the source properties. The definition of this class is important to you code, so you need to define it.

Then, as you iterate the original list (`sourceList`), when `Date` or `ID` changes, you create a new result object and add it to the result list. If the `Date` and `ID` are the same, you compare and increment the change-counters as needed.

As for property 6, I'm not sure I understand the requirement for it, so I'll let you work on that.

For property 7, that is really a property derived from properties 4 and 5, so it can be implemented as a getter method of the result class, deriving its value from the two counter fields.